# Adicionar parametro no final do link com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, link, redirect

Galera, estou tentando pegar algumas URL's especificas em uma página, e adicionar um parâmetro no fim do link, mas não estou obtendo sucesso, pois é retornado o objeto ao invés da string do link + o parâmetro.

Fiz um exemplo bem simples do código:

```
var links = jQuery('a[href*="google.com.br"]');
links.attr('href', links + 'parametros_adicionais');
```

A execução dessa código me retorna a URL com esse parâmetro no fim **[object%20Object]test**

Será que vocês podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Links é um objeto que contem todos os elementos, deves percorrer os `a[href*="google.com.br"]` e mudar um de cada vez.

```js
var param = 'SoUmParametro';
var src;
var links = jQuery('a[href*="google.com.br"]');
links.each(function() {
   src = $(this).prop('href');
   $(this).prop('href', src+param);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://google.com.br">link1</a>
<a href="http://google.com.br">link2</a>
```

Comment: Salvou cara, e de quebra ainda aprendi a usar melhor o jQuery.

Vou tomar vergonha na cara e explorar todo essa lib, não aguento mais ter essas dúvidas simples.

Obrigadão Miguel!

Comment: @thierryrenematos de nada, não te preocupes com isso todos nós já tivemos estas duvidas

Answer (score 1):

O correto seria assim:

```
var links = jQuery('a[href*="google.com.br"]');
links.attr('href', links.attr('href') + 'parametros_adicionais');
```

Lembrando que o código com Jquery deve estar sempre dentro de um "ready":

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var links = jQuery('a[href*="google.com.br"]');
       links.attr('href', links.attr('href') + 'parametros_adicionais');
    })
```